# Steady-State Current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

I am in the process of completing some homework and have come across a question that says: "What is the steady-state current?" It is asking in reference to a circuit that includes two capacitors in parrallel and a DC source of 24V and an AC source given by $\epsilon = 20 \cos(120 \pi t)\ \text{V}$, where $t$ is in seconds. I assume that it is asking when the current is constant. Because naturally the current is not constant due to the AC source, would I just consider the DC source for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steady state means, in this context, ignoring transients due to initial conditions.

For a capacitor, the steady state current due to a DC voltage source is zero.

The steady state current due to an AC source is simply the (constant) amplitude of the sinusoidal current.

To be clear, the current *is* changing in time and so is not constant.  But, the *amplitude* of the current is constant, i.e.,

$$i_C = A \cos(\omega t + \phi)$$

where $A$ is a constant.  This is called AC or sinusoidal steady state.

[image]

[Credit](https://books.google.com/books?id=-8xuxa1r1J4C&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=define%20sinusoidal%20steady%20state&source=bl&ots=-avtzd8r73&sig=VhYW7Y-YTAYvHkcBAgERiIEAnPw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCGoVChMItc_y0-HwyAIVxTEmCh1bswzY#v=onepage&q=define%20sinusoidal%20steady%20state&f=false)

Comment: That was brilliantly explained. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should ignore DC, rather than AC, as the circuit is open for DC. The steady current would be AC current caused by the AC source. The DC source would only be responsible for a transient process at the beginning (if any).

Comment: So then would I be looking to find the RMS value for the AC source? I'm not sure how to find a steady current due to the nature of AC always changing.

Comment: @Cremedekhan: I don't know the format of the answer that is expected from you, but I would say that the steady current would be AC current with such and such amplitude and frequency (maybe phase as well).